# Smoothing splines with multiple independent variables in R

Tags: r, splines, multivariate-regression

I'm using `smooth.spline` for some basic smoothing splines.  However, I need to switch to a function that allows me to use multiple independent variables.  I'm having trouble finding one, other than [`mars`](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/mda/html/mars.html), which is giving me bizarre results so I think it may not be what I'm looking for.  My stat background is very limited, and I don't think the type of spline matters too much, so I was wondering if there is a real basic smoothing spline like `smooth.spline` that works for multiple independent variables.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [generalized additive models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_additive_model) (GAM)? It fits a sum of splines across your independent variables. The `gam` package in R is one good choice.

Comment: And mgcv package is an even better choice!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `gam` is giving me fairly-similar values to `smooth.spline` when I just use the one independent variable, but when I switched to two, it got weird. I'm using the smoothing modifier `s()` on each independent variable - is this correct? Let me play with it a bit more, and if I can't get it I'll update my OP with an example. Thanks!